# Query the Unioned Results of Multiple Tables With Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to query 3 tables and grab to most recent activity over all of the tables, as determined by a CreatedDate time stamp. Each of the tables is represented by an entity in my domain model, and I'm using Entity Framework Code First (no data migrations) to map my domain.

I know what the query should look like in SQL, but I'm not sure how to craft it in LinqToEntities or EntitySql. Can you please tell me how to do this in Entity Framework, and even if it's appropriate to perform this query with Entity Framework query methods?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here are my entities (primary keys are on a base class):

```
public class Group : EntityThatBelongsToApartmentComplex<int>
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string GroupDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; protected set; }

    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }    
}


public class Activity : EntityThatBelongsToApartmentComplex<int>
{
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; protected set; }       
}


public class Comment : EntityBase<int>
{
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; protected set; }
}
```

Here's my feeling of what the query should look like in SQL:

```
WITH NewsFeed AS (
SELECT 
    g.Id AS ItemId
    ,'Group' AS ItemType
    ,g.GroupName AS HeaderText
    ,g.CreatedDate
    ,g.CreatedById AS CreatorId
    ,u.UserName AS CreatorName
FROM Groups g
    INNER JOIN UserProfiles u on g.CreatedById = u.Id

UNION 

SELECT 
    a.Id AS ItemId
    ,'Activity' AS ItemType
    ,a.Name AS HeaderText
    ,a.CreatedDate
    ,a.CreatedById AS CreatorId
    ,u.UserName
FROM Activities a
    INNER JOIN UserProfiles u on a.CreatedById = u.Id

UNION 

SELECT 
    c.Id AS ItemId
    ,'Comment' AS ItemType
    ,c.Text AS HeaderText
    ,c.CreatedDate
    ,c.CreatedById AS CreatorId
    ,u.UserName
FROM Comments c
    INNER JOIN UserProfiles u on c.CreatedById = u.Id
) 
SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM NewsFeed
    ORDER BY CreatedDate
```

Comment: What `DbSets` have you got in your context? Is there any inheritance mapping?

Comment: @GertArnold No inheritance mapping, so Table Per Concrete Class, I believe it's called. I have Group, Activity, and Comment DbSets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use projection. Simply project the result of each single query into an anonymous (or not anonymous) object that has the same parameter (name & type must match). Then you can do something like this:

```
var query =
    context.SetOne.Select(x => new { Key = x.ID })
        .Union(context.SetTwo.Select(x => new { Key = x.AnotherKey }))
        .Union(context.SetThree.Select(x => new { Key = 5 }));
```